# Html link to different folder name change

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is there any way to have an html link, and in code, take the current url link and change a folder to a different path?

I basically have a bunch of English pages and a bunch of French Pages, the only difference in the URL is the /English/folder and french, /Francais/folder. I would like to create a link on the English page 'French' that when I clicked it would automatically go to the French equivalent of that page.

Could this be done? Right now all the links are hard coded in manually but I'd like to take the English page, click a link and automatically change the url to French to go to the French equivalent folder.

All pages in English have an equivalent French location and these links are manually created, I'd like to have an automatic code so when I clicked on the 'French' it would take me to the French equivalent.

Comment: What you are wanting is a [Variable](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/variable) -- What language you write said *variable* in is up to you .. But what you're asking could easily be done with a backend language such as PHP or Python, OR could easily be done in JavaScript as well ....   I suggest you look into the basics of creating *dynamic content*

Comment: Yes a variable would be it, when I click on the French link it would take the English URL automatically swap the /English to /French and go to that page.  But I just have no idea how to go about doing it. The reason I'm asking as well is that I have 1200 pages in English that if I can have a single line of code to swap automatically it would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If the path looks like I think, you can try this stupid solution to fix the problem or modify it that suits you better.

- folder main

  - folder English
  - folder French

in folder English/test.php

```
<body id='English'>
  <div>
    <a class='language' id='English' target='_self' href='#'>English</a>&emsp;
    <a class='language' id='French' target='_self' href='#'>French</a>&emsp;
    <a class='language' id='Japanese' target='_self' href='#'>Japanese(no link)</a>
  </div>
  English test page
</body>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    //hyperlink click
    document.querySelectorAll("a[class='language']").forEach((hyperlink) => {
      hyperlink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        let language_now = document.querySelector("body").id;
        top.location.href = window.location.pathname.replace(language_now, event.target.id);
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

in folder French/test.php

```
<body id='French'>
  <div>
    <a class='language' id='English' target='_self' href='#'>English</a>&emsp;
    <a class='language' id='French' target='_self' href='#'>French</a>&emsp;
    <a class='language' id='Japanese' target='_self' href='#'>Japanese(no link)</a>
  </div>
  French test page
</body>


<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    //hyperlink click
    document.querySelectorAll("a[class='language']").forEach((hyperlink) => {
      hyperlink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        let language_now = document.querySelector("body").id;
        top.location.href = window.location.pathname.replace(language_now, event.target.id);
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

edit:I tried to change it to hyperlink, and only need to edit id of each element to switch language page.

Comment: Yes the folder structure is simple with English and French in separate folders. So if the English URL is ../test/English/filename.htm, the french would be ../test/French/filename.htm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This code is good, but instead of a button how would I do it just for a link? Meaning change the button to just a simple hyperlink.

Comment: @slang75  I've changed it to hyperlink, does that fit your needs?